# Tune script environment of IronPython to use itertools

Tags: c#, ironpython, python-itertools

Question ago ([Reseting generator object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/reseting-generator-object-in-python)) I was recommended to use itertools.tee. Actually I'm using IronPython, in the library we can see many usage of this feature, but there is no implementation (in *.py). That is why I'm confusing how to include this package to my c# project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

itertools is a built-in module.  In IronPython the majority of the built-in modules live in IronPython.Modules.dll.  You should be able to just add a reference to this DLL and it should get deployed w/ your app by VS.  IronPython should then pick it up and it should be availble from there.