# How to get the item currently pointed at by iterator without incrementing?

Tags: python, iterator

Is there a way to get the item pointed at by an iterator in python without incrementing the iterator itself? For example how would I implement the following with iterators:

```
looking_for = iter(when_to_change_the_mode)
for l in listA:
    do_something(looking_for.current())
    if l == looking_for.current():
        next(looking_for)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
looking_for = iter(when_to_change_the_mode)
current = next(looking_for)
for l in listA:
    do_something(current)
    if l == current:
        current = next(looking_for)
```

Question:
What if at the end of the iterator? The `next` function allows for a default parameter.

Comment: Howto check if have a next iteration?

Answer (score 22):

Iterators don't have a way to get the current value.  If you want that, keep a reference to it yourself, or wrap your iterator to hold onto it for you.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a built-in way. It's pretty easy to just wrap the iterator in question inside a custom iterator that buffers one element.

For example: [How to look ahead one element in a Python generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425270/how-to-look-ahead-one-element-in-a-python-generator)

Answer (score 3):

When I needed to do this, I solved it by creating class like:

```
class Iterator:
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iterator = iterator
        self.current = None
    def __next__(self):
        try:
            self.current = next(self.iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            self.current = None
        finally:
            return self.current
```

This way you're able to use next(itr) just like for standard iterator, and you're able to get current value by calling itr.current.