# While using the range() function, is it possible to recall a result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I'm using  `iter(range())`, but I also need to use the results twice, assuming `j=iter(range(n,2n)`)

`next(j)` would be n, but then I need that certain `next(j)` again without stepping forward, Is that possible without further complications?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily write a generator which repeats each element of a given iterator twice:

```
def repeat_iter(iter, n = 2):
    for x in iter:
        for i in range(n):
            yield x

for x in repeat_iter(range(n)):
    print x
```

If what your use case requires is *looking ahead*, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425270/how-to-look-ahead-one-element-in-a-python-generator) for some nice solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to explicitly get two iterators, using `itertools.tee`:

```
iter1,iter2 = itertools.tee(iter(range(5,10)))

next(iter1)
Out[15]: 5

next(iter2)
Out[16]: 5
```

This can be more flexible depending on what you're doing, but the downside is that you need to make sure you're going 1-for-1 consuming from both iterators.

But honestly I don't think I've ever found myself doing this with `range`.  When you assign `next()` to a variable, you can access it as many times as you want (*a la* `for i in range`), so...

Answer (score 0):

or You can use generator statement

```
for i in (j for j in range(n, 2 * n) for k in range(2)):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip`:

```
for a, b in zip(range(...), range(...)):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [shx2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19575221/923794) to be the correct answer to the question.

However, in the case where

- you only need to reuse some of the values, and do not know at the time the iterator is created which ones you need to reappear, or
- some of the values may have to be repeated more often than others,

then here's a different generator that can react on feedback via the [`send()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send).

```
def iter_with_standstill(iter):
    standstill = False
    for x in iter:
        while True:
            pause = yield x
            if pause is not None:
                standstill = pause
                yield None
            if not standstill:
                break
```

The trick used is that any call of `generator.send(value)` will send back the `value` to the generator which receives it as the result of `yield`. As any `send()` will cause the generator to also immediately run up to the next `yield()`, we `yield(None)` here to give back control immediately to the calling code. This method makes `send()` to truly operate as a one way operation.

Here's how to use it:

```
orig = range(10)
paused = iter_with_standstill(orig)

waiting = None
for x in paused:
    if x in [4,7]:
        if waiting is None:
            waiting = 3
        waiting -= 1
        if waiting > 0:
            paused.send(True)
        else:
            paused.send(False)
            waiting = None
    print(x, end=' ')
print()
```

The whole point of the `waiting` variable is to pause at the values 4 and 7, and re-iterating those values up to a total of 3 times. The output looks like:

```
0 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 7 8 9
```