# How to "peek" at iterator, while leaving the items on?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

Let's say I want to see the fifth item of an iterator, but I want to leave all the items on. What is the best way to do that? Is there a module? I could probably hack together a function that makes a new iterator, but I want to know if its already been done?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425270/how-to-look-ahead-one-element-in-a-python-generator

Comment: What do you mean by "*leave all the items on*"?

Answer (score 7):

I think what you want is [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), which essentially makes two iterators under the hood. Use one to peek, expending the items therein, while the contents "remain" in the other one.

```
In [10]: g = (i for i in range(5))

In [11]: a,b = itertools.tee(g)

In [12]: next(a)
Out[12]: 0

In [13]: next(a)
Out[13]: 1

In [14]: next(a)
Out[14]: 2

In [15]: next(b)
Out[15]: 0
```

Notice that `next(b)` returns `0` instead of `3`, which is the behavior you are looking for

Answer (score 5):

The [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) third-party library has a [`more_itertools.spy`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.spy) tool that allows you to lookahead:

```
import more_itertools as mit

iterator = iter("abcdefg")
lookahead, iterable = mit.spy(iterator, 6) 
lookahead[5]
# 'f'
```

From the [source](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py#L705-L708), this tool essentially implements what @inspectorG4dget described. See also [`more_itertools.peekable`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.peekable).

Comment: Doesn't the current implementation (as of May 3rd, 2019) break on python 3.7 because of  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/ ?

Comment: As of November 2019, more-itertools [works](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/3e3a9a7671cd047988580aa584c4b3f18cd635f7/tox.ini#L2) with Python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8.

Comment: Development on Python 2.7 was deprecated in 2019 (version 6.0.0).  This particular recipe works on Python 2.7 as late as version 5.0.0.  `pip install more_itertools < 6.0.0`