# Python: How to assert the type of the first element of an iterable?

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

I'm searching for a "pythonic" way to assert the type of the first element in an iterable.

For example if i have the following list:

```
l = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), ...]
```

And a function which it is passed into, i can simply do:

```
def foo(l):
    assert isinstance(l[0], tuple)
    ...
```

Now i'm searching for something similar to this that works with iterators as well, but doesn't load the whole list into ram. I can try:

```
def foo(it):
    assert isinstance(next(it), tuple)
    ...

it = iter(l)
foo(it)
```

but this obviously modifies the state of the iterator in the assertion.

Is there an easy way to peek at the first element of an iterator without modifying it?

Comment: thanks, didn't find that dup :-/ but using `itertools.chain` as in their answer or `itertools.tee` as in mine below is kind of the same...

Comment: FYI I found it by searching *"Python peek iterator"* - see also http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577361-peek-ahead-an-iterator/

Comment: yeah, i was too focused on "assert first element of iterator", i guess... i'll leave this for other people to find.

Answer (score 2):

My current (as i find ugly) solution is:

```
from itertools import tee

def foo(it):
    if __debug__:
        it1, it2 = tee(it, 2)
        assert isinstance(next(it1), tuple)
        it = it2
    ...
```

Is there a better / cooler way to peek at the first element that i'm not aware of?

Comment: Not AFAIK, and I can't imagine another one that would reliably work on any iterable.

Comment: Heck ! reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/2425347/41316, there's indeed a cleaner, simpler and really obvious one ;)

Comment: Doesn't `tee` force buffering of every element from the generator, since it doesn't know that `it1` won't be used again?