# Python itertools—takewhile(): multiple predicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose a generator yields the below tuples one by one (from left to right)

```
(1, 2, 3), (2, 5, 6), (3, 7, 10), (4, 5, 11), (3, 5, 15), (4, 5, 9), (4, 6, 12)
...
```

and suppose I'd like to iterate  as long as the predicate is true. Let that predicate be `sum(yielded_value) < 20`. Then the iterator will stop by `(3, 5, 15)`. I can do it with, say:

```
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: sum(x) < 20, some_generator()))
```

Question, how do I write a similar expression with two predicates? Suppose I want:

```
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: sum(x) < 20 and first_value_of_tuple > 3, some_generator()))
```

(which, in this case, stop by `(4, 6, 12)`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access to elements of each tuple with index.

```
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: sum(x) < 20 and x[0] > 3, some_generator()))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to point at `next yield` (or `previously yielded value`?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't look back, unless you store the value, but you can look ahead with `next` for more see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425270/how-to-look-ahead-one-element-in-a-python-generator

Answer (score 2):

Since everything in `itertools` is lazily iterated, and you are using `and` for two predicates, you can simply use two `takewhile` iterators. Sometimes I find this more readable than putting both predicates in a single predicate function or lambda:

```
lessthan20 = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: sum(x) < 20, some_generator())
greaterthan3 = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0] > 3, lessthan20)
list(greaterthan3)
```

It also makes it so that you don't have a single huge one liner if you need to add even more predicates in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have additional predicates and need to access all the elements of your tuples you can also unpack them in your lambda function:

```
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda (x, y, z): x+y+z < 20 and x > 3 and y < 7 and z > 1, some_generator()))
```

This also asserts that all your tuples have length 3. If you get a tuple with 4 values, it fails hard, as opposed to continuing silently. Obviously only useful in some contexts.