# Python Loop Utilising next() Skipping Lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script which i am using to parse a text file.
The script has a While loop in it as their maybe multiple next lines. 
My current script is having an issue where it is skipping lines. I am pretty sure its something to do with my use of "next()" and its placement, but i cant figure it out.
This is an example of the text file:

```
object-group network TestNetwork1
 description TestDescription
 network-object host TestHost
 network-object host TestHost
 network-object host TestHost
 network-object host TestHost
object-group network TestNetwork2
 description TestDescription
 network-object host TestHost
object-group network TestNetwork3
 description TestDescription
 network-object host TestHost
object-group network TestNetwork4
 description TestDescription
 network-object host TestHost
object-group network TestNetwork5
 description TestDescription
 network-object host TestHost
object-group network TestNetwork6
 description TestDescription
 network-object host TestHost
object-group network TestNetwork7
 description TestDescription
 network-object host TestHost
object-group network TestNetwork8
 description TestDescription
 network-object host TestHost
object-group network TestNetwork9
 description TestDescription
 network-object host TestHost
object-group network TestNetwork10s
 description TestDescription
 network-object host TestHost
```

Here is the script:

```
    import csv
Count = 0
objects = open("test-object-groups.txt", 'r+')
iobjects = iter(objects)

with open('object-group-test.csv', 'wb+') as filename2:
    writer2 = csv.writer(filename2)
    for lines in iobjects:
        if lines.startswith("object-group network"):
            print lines
            Count += 1
            linesplit = lines.split()
            writer2.writerow([linesplit[2]])
            while True:
                nextline = str(next(iobjects))
                if nextline.startswith(" network-object") or nextline.startswith(" description"):
                    nextlinesplit = nextline.split()
                    if nextlinesplit[1] <> "host" and nextlinesplit[1] <> "object" and nextlinesplit[0] <> "description":
                        writer2.writerow(['','subnet', nextlinesplit[1], nextlinesplit[2]])
                    elif nextlinesplit[1] == "host":
                        writer2.writerow(['',nextlinesplit[1], nextlinesplit[2]])
                    elif nextlinesplit[1] == "object":
                        writer2.writerow(['',nextlinesplit[1], nextlinesplit[2]])
                    elif nextlinesplit[0] == "description":
                        writer2.writerow(['',nextlinesplit[0]])

                elif nextline.startswith("object-group"):
                    break

print Count
```

Here is the output showing that it is skipping lines:

```
object-group network TestNetwork1

object-group network TestNetwork3

object-group network TestNetwork5

object-group network TestNetwork7

object-group network TestNetwork9

5
```

As you can see above, the line items are skipping.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out code until you find the line that cause the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
for lines in iobjects:
    ...
    ...
    while True:
        nextline = str(next(iobjects))
```

Of course it will skip a line. You are calling `next(iobjects)` while iterating over `iobjects`, therefore the next line is consumed and not handled by the `for` loop.

Consider this file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

And this code:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        if int(line.strip()) % 2 == 0:
            next(f)
```

The output is:

```
1

2

4

6

8

10

12

14
```

Every second line is missing since we call `next` if the number is even.

Suggested solutions:

1. Use `itertools.tee` to create 2 different generators. Probably the least straightforward solution.
2. Use `f.readlines()` and operate on a list of lines from the file instead of the iterator. This way you can work with indices.
3. Use the `more-itertools` package which creates a "peekable" iterator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27698681/1453822
4. Don't parse the file line by line. Use regex to extract information from the file block by block. For example, the regex `r'(object-group.*?)(?=$|object-group)'` will do. (I'm sure this is far from the optimal regex). Make sure you are using the `re.DOTALL` flag.

   ```
   import re

   with open('test.txt') as f:
       file_content = f.read()

   for group in re.findall(r'(object-group.*?)(?=$|object-group)', file_content, re.DOTALL):
       print(group)

   # object-group network TestNetwork1
   #  description TestDescription
   #  network-object host TestHost
   #  network-object host TestHost
   #  network-object host TestHost
   #  network-object host TestHost
   # 
   # object-group network TestNetwork2
   #  description TestDescription
   #  network-object host TestHost
   # 
   # object-group network TestNetwork3
   #  description TestDescription
   #  network-object host TestHost
   # 
   # object-group network TestNetwork4
   #  description TestDescription
   #  network-object host TestHost
   # 
   # object-group network TestNetwork5
   #  description TestDescription
   #  network-object host TestHost
   # 
   # object-group network TestNetwork6
   #  description TestDescription
   #  network-object host TestHost
   # 
   # object-group network TestNetwork7
   #  description TestDescription
   #  network-object host TestHost
   # 
   # object-group network TestNetwork8
   #  description TestDescription
   #  network-object host TestHost
   # 
   # object-group network TestNetwork9
   #  description TestDescription
   #  network-object host TestHost
   # 
   # object-group network TestNetwork10s
   #  description TestDescription
   #  network-object host TestHost
   ```

**As a side note**, `iobjects = iter(objects)` is redundant. `open` already returns an iterator.

Comment: I thought that may be the case. Do you have any recommendations on methods to achieve the right outcome?

Comment: wrote it 1 minute faster than me :)

Comment: @Dr.Pepper See updated answer with several solutions

Comment: Thanks. The issue i have is that the file in question can be thousands of lines long ( Cisco Firewall Configuration). I am trying to extract the Object-Groups into a CSV file. Whenever i reach a line that has Object-Group, i need to read the next "X" number of lines, which may be 1 or 50 lines. I need to have a dig around to see how to do this with ReadLines as i looked into this previously and couldnt find an answer

Comment: @Dr.Pepper Don't parse the file line by line. Use a regex `r'(object-group.*?)(?=$|object-group)'` (I'm sure this is far from the optimal regex). Make sure you are using the `re.DOTALL` flag.

Comment: Thanks DeepSpace. Matching the RegEx will only match on that one line if i am not mistaken? How can i then read the follow X amount of lines to see if they start with "description" or "network-object" so i can put the description or network-object under the correct Object-Group in a csv? I would still need to read the next line like i am currently doing wouldnt i?

Comment: @Dr.Pepper no, and no. See my answer.