# iterators in python 3 and the print function

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

other questions have already clarified, that in python3 `filter` returns an iterator. to print it, one may use the list function:

```
odds = filter(lambda x: x>2,[1,2,3,1.1,1.2,1.3,4])
print(list(odds))
```

this prints correctly:

```
[3, 4]
```

however, the execution of list 'consumes' the iterator produced by list. so, if I call again:

```
print(list(odds))
```

this prints an empty string. most importantly, if I use the list function to see the iterator, then I cannot use it later in my script (e.g. as an iterator), because it has been consumed/emptied/iterated.
is there a way to see the iterator without consuming  it or is it like the uncertainty principle in quantum mechanics, that if I observe an iterator I also modify it? I think the answer is no, but I thought it would be useful for other stackoverflowers to know this issue.

Comment: Just save it in a list

Comment: Also possibly [How to look ahead one element (peek) in a Python generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425270/how-to-look-ahead-one-element-peek-in-a-python-generator).

Comment: @glibdud Using tee, as suggested in the duplicate, is useless when traversing the whole iterator. It's more efficient to cast it to a list then because tee simply saves it as a list and adds some overhead

Comment: @OlivierMelançon A lot of things are discussed in the duplicate, including the idea of using a list or simply regenerating the iterator. There isn't anything particularly new about this question.

Comment: @glibdud You are right, I read too fast

Comment: I think the answer to my question is then 'no'. Creating a list, using tee, or producing a function that outputs the iterator (see below) are workarounds, each has pros and cons (use of memory vs. computing costs). True, these are explained in the proposed duplicate. But I believe my question is formulated in a different way and could be still useful. Do you still suggest to delete it because it is a duplicate?

Comment: @fabiob No, duplicate are not necessarly bad. They are way to reword an already existing question. So please do not delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lambda that returns a new iterator:

```
odds = lambda: filter(lambda x: x>2,[1,2,3,1.1,1.2,1.3,4])
print(list(odds())) # [3, 4]
print(list(odds())) # [3, 4]
```