# How to get multiple instances of a generator function

Tags: python, generator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clone a Python generator object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945155/how-to-clone-a-python-generator-object)

Suppose I have a generator 'stuff_to_try', I can try them one by one but if I had a method that wanted to go through the generator and that method is recursive, I want to let each recursion get a fresh new generator that starts at the first yield rather than where the last recursion left off.

```
def solve(something):
    if exit_condition(something):
        return

    next_to_try = stuff_to_try.next()
    while not if_works(next_to_try):
        next_to_try = stuff_to_try.next()
    solve(do_something(something))
```

Of course I can define stuff_to_try inside the recursive function but is there a better way? Is there an equivalent of stuff_to_try.clone().reset() or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the generator in a function:

```
def stuff_to_try():
    return (i for i in [stuff, to, try])
```

Then each time you want a new generator, just call the function.

```
def solve(something):
    if exit_condition(something):
        return

    for next_to_try in stuff_to_try():
        if_works(next_to_try):
            break
    solve(do_something(something))
```

If I read your question correctly, what you actually want is this:

```
def solve(something):
    if exit_condition(something):
        return

    for each in [stuff, to, try]:
        if_works(each):
            break
    solve(do_something(something))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is make it a list, then it will have the behaviour you want:

```
stuff_to_try = [i for i in [stuff, to, try]]
```

Any efficiency gains from being lazy are likely to be lost by recalculating the values again and again.

Comment: oops, bad example in the question. The list would be easier since I'm implying that there's a short finite list to generate but the real question is how to clone generators so suppose the generator is more complicated

Comment: Definitely the simplest, but sometimes not practical. A list might not fit in memory.

Comment: Of course, that's the downside. That said, it may be the only practical solution depending on the generator at hand.

Comment: why not `stuff_to_try = (i for i in [stuff, to, try])`?