# Not entering the for loop in python 2.7.2

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, for-loop

Here is the code I was using to manipulate a CSV file. It is not entering the 2nd and 3rd for loops.

```
import csv
f=open("/Users/shivendraagrawal/Desktop/Training Dataset.csv","rU")
cr = csv.reader(f)
mapping={}
out={}
i=0
for row in cr:
      i=i+1
      mapping[row[0]]=0
      out[row[0]]=0
for row in cr:
      print "hi"
      mapping[row[0]]=mapping[row[0]]+row[5]
      if row[6]=="TRUE":
            out[row[0]]=out[row[0]]+1

for row in cr:
      print mapping[row[0]] +'  '+out[row[0]]

print i
```

Comment: you need to rewind it to initial position after first and second loop

Comment: I think my iterator was defined only for one For Loop's scope. Isn't it?
If not, can you suggest me how to do that.

Comment: Read below I have posted an answer @Vladimir Sinenko also posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `f.seek(0)` to rewind back after first and second loop e.g. before second loop:

```
f.seek(0)
for row in cr:
    # loop code
```

Read: [from Python doc code](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer)

Give it a try!!

Comment: Why are you rewinding back the 'f' object while I am iterating over 'cr'? And thanks a lot, it is working now.

Comment: @Shivendra I just learn the trick from linked page. through `cr` not reset.

Comment: @Shivendra It's part of the way the `csv` module is designed. The position of the `reader` is linked to the position of the file pointer. Advancing your `reader` moves the file pointer forwards; moving the file pointer back again resets the `reader`.

Comment: @poorsod Thanks as learner I posted this answer. Can you provide some link to read further.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It's basically because CSV readers work on any iterable. Here are the docs on [file objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) and the way they iterate; here are the docs on [CSV readers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#reader-objects). If you're using Python 3, file objects are implemented somewhat differently, though they expose the same interface.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the iterator more than once, but the iterators are single-shot only.

Just make a copy of the `cr` contents when reading it, and iterate through that:

```
cr_copy = [c for c in cr]
for row in cr_copy:
```

Or, there is a more Pythonic way to do that: you can clone the iterator three times by using the [itertools.tee](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945155/how-to-clone-a-python-generator-object)):

```
import itertools

cr1, cr2 = itertools.tee(cr)
for row in cr1:
     # first loop

for row in cr2:
     # secondloop
```

Comment: I tried with a different iterator too. (row1, row2) but the result was the same.

Comment: I just wished there was a way to accept more than one answers. Got it. Awesomely presented :)