# Listize a generator in python

Tags: python, generator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reseting generator object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/reseting-generator-object-in-python)

I often have the following problem in python: I have a generator which I am using in several calls to compute different values, like this:

```
mygenerator = generate_data()
value1 = compute1(mygenerator)
value2 = compute2(mygenerator)
```

The problem is, of course, that compute2 will find no data, since the generator has been consumed. So I am forced to "listize" the generator:

```
mygenerator = generate_data()
mylist = listize_generator(mygenerator)
value1 = compute1(mylist)
value2 = compute2(mylist)
```

Is there another method to solve this problem?

Comment: what does `listize_generator` do? Can you just invoke: `mylist = list(mygenerator)`?

Comment: Indeed, that's is what it does. Is there any other solution to this problem? Having a list of the generated data can be memory intensive.

Answer (score 0):

You need co-routines to send the generator output to multiple consumers.

e.g. http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/cobroadcast.py

I recommend reading all of http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/ since it's an excellent introduction.

Comment: You might also want to look at tee(), from itertools: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee