# Python 3.6: async version of islice?

Tags: iterator, python-itertools, python-asyncio, python-3.6

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
import asyncio
from itertools import islice

async def generate_numbers(n):
    for x in range(n):
        yield x


async def consume_numbers(n):
    async for x in generate_numbers(n):
        print(x)

async def consume_some_numbers(n,m):
    async for x in islice(generate_numbers(n),m): #<-- This doesn't work.  islice doesn't recognize async iterators as iterators.
        print(x)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(consume_numbers(10))
loop.run_until_complete(consume_some_numbers(10,5))
```

Is there a way to make this work, or at least get similar functionality?

Comment: check my [unordered_bulks](https://gist.github.com/muayyad-alsadi/287d668686298a43f1ae9585c0f98e5d), because aislice runs them sequentially, and in most cases this is not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an attempt to implement asyncio friendly [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) (and enumerate):

```
import asyncio
import sys

import random


async def aenumerate(aiterable):
    i = 0
    async for x in aiterable:
        yield i, x
        i += 1


async def aislice(aiterable, *args):
    s = slice(*args)
    it = iter(range(s.start or 0, s.stop or sys.maxsize, s.step or 1))
    try:
        nexti = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    async for i, element in aenumerate(aiterable):
        if i == nexti:
            yield element
            try:
                nexti = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                return


async def generate_numbers(n):
    for x in range(n):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.4))
        yield x


async def consume_numbers(tag, n):
    print(tag, "start")
    async for x in generate_numbers(n):
        print(tag, x)
    print(tag, "done")


async def consume_some_numbers(tag, n, a, b, step=1):
    print(tag, "start")
    async for x in aislice(generate_numbers(n), a, b, step):
        print(tag, x)
    print(tag, "done")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([
    consume_numbers("A", 5),
    consume_numbers("B", 10),
    consume_some_numbers("C", 10, 0, 5),
    consume_some_numbers("D", 30, 3, 20, 4),
    consume_some_numbers("E", 10, 3, 8, 2),
]))
loop.close()
```

This was **not** tested in a real world application, comments welcome :-)

Comment: It looks like you just took the version from the python docs and replaced the `for`s with `async for`s, and make the function async?  For some reason, I tried everything *but* that...  Thanks

Comment: Yep, exactly, and added `aenumerate` and another `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

The [aiostream](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream) library provides generator-based operators for asynchronous iteration. See this example using [stream.take](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#aiostream.stream.take):

```
import asyncio
from aiostream import stream

async def generate_numbers(n):
    for x in range(n):
        yield x

async def consume_some_numbers(n,m):
    async for x in stream.take(generate_numbers(n), m):
        print(x)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(consume_some_numbers(10, 5))
```

All the stream operators return an enhanced asynchronous iterable providing extra features such as slicing support. Consider the following example:

```
import asyncio
from aiostream import stream

async def main():
    xs = stream.count()
    ys = xs[5:10:2]
    async for y in ys:
        print(y)  # Prints 5, 7, 9

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

See more examples in this [demonstration](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream#demonstration) and the [documentation](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html).