# Python nested generators not working

Tags: python, generator

I am practising with generators and I wonder why the following code does not print 16 pairs but only 4.

```
def range_generator_function(my_range):
    for i in my_range:
        yield i

gen1=range_generator_function(range(1,5))
gen2=range_generator_function(range(1,5))

def pairs_generator_function(gen1,gen2):
    for it1 in gen1:
        for it2 in gen2:
            yield [it1,it2]

my_gen = pairs_generator_function(gen1,gen2)

for it in my_gen:
    print(it)
```

The output is

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
```

While the output I expect is

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 1]
[4, 2]
[4, 3]
[4, 4]
```

Comment: Generators *are single-pass iterators*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual output is correct.  Your `gen2` instance is completely exhausted by the first inner loop:

```
def pairs_generator_function(gen1,gen2):
    for it1 in gen1:
        for it2 in gen2:  # <--- this consumes gen2
            yield [it1,it2]
```

On the subsequent iterations, iterating `gen2` again is empty.

Comment: How can I make it usable again?

Comment: You can not.  Generators are one-shot.  You will have to save the values during the first iteration, or create a new generator.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/resetting-generator-object-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You exhausted gen2 after the first time through the inner loop.  You no longer have anything in that stream, so the other three values of `it1` have nothing with which to pair.  You need to restart `gen2` every time through.  Consider `itertools.tee` for cloning more copies.

Comment: I don't see this as complex, but it is a minor shame to have to go through gen1 an extra time.  However, it does leave the solution encapsulated.

Answer (score 1):

The output you get is due to the fact that on the second iteration, the generator `gen2` has been exhausted.

You can either make a `list` out of it to store its output prior to looping or copy it with `itertools.tee` on every iteration. The former will not be able to handle infinite generators, but before implementing the later let me point out that you are actually reimplementing `itertools.product`.

```
from itertools import product

my_gen = product(gen1, gen2)

for it in my_gen:
    print(it)
```

Comment: this is really interesting!

Comment: @Nisba I am not sure someone showed code to fix your issue, so I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code so I get the wanted output, now the generator is recreated every time inside the outer loop.

```
def range_generator_function(my_range):
    for i in my_range:
        yield i

def pairs_generator_function():
    gen1=range_generator_function(range(1,5))
    for it1 in gen1:
        gen2=range_generator_function(range(1,5))
        for it2 in gen2:
            yield [it1,it2]

my_gen = pairs_generator_function()

for it in my_gen:
    print(it)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @wim pointed out, your generator is entirely exhausted after the first instance of iteration. However, to prevent this, cast `gen1` and `gen2` as lists when passing them to `pairs_generator_function`. However, you can use `itertools.tee` to store two copies of the original generator: one to pass to the function as a list, and the other for future use:

```
import itertools

def range_generator_function(my_range):
   for i in my_range:
     yield i

gen1=range_generator_function(range(1,5))
gen2=range_generator_function(range(1,5))

def pairs_generator_function(gen1,gen2):
  for it1 in gen1:
    for it2 in gen2:
        yield [it1,it2]

gen1, gen1_l = itertools.tee(gen1)
gen2, gen2_l = itertools.tee(gen2)
print(list(pairs_generator_function(list(gen1_l), list(gen2_l))))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
```

Notice, however, that `gen1` and gen2` still point to the items in memory:

```
>>next(gen1)
1
>>next(gen2)
1
```