# resetting the start value of for loop in Range(start, end) in python

Tags: python, loops

I am avoiding using a while loop

In Java, I could do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(.......) i = 0;
    //this will reset i to 0
}
```

In python this doesn't work:

```
j = 1
for i in range(j, n):
  if .....:
      j = 1
```

Is there a way i can reset the value of j.

NB: A while loop would solve the problem for me but I don't want to use it. Thanks

Comment: Using while loop would be simple here, why do you want to stick to for loop? I am not sure if it's possible with the for loop!

Comment: You want a `for` loop within a `while` one no? `while True: for i in range(j, n): if ...: break` etc.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a while loop in this scenario?

Comment: For example, you can simply regenerate the value of 1 (while 1 < 10) within a while loop in this case. Within a for loop, this obviously won't work since the value is generated at the beginning of the for loop within a specified range in Python. Differences between Java and Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3 `range(..)` returns range object, which is, even though it can't be exhausted like generators, is immutable and you can't rewind it.

May be you can look in [Resetting generator object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/resetting-generator-object-in-python) - there is more information about it and some methods to bypass similar problems

In python2 `range(..)` returns list, but you still can't rewind it, because `for i in range(..)` still iterates over list sequentially and `i` is just a single value from list and overriding `i` value won't work, because list still references the same object, while you just changed where `i` variable points

Comment: This is wrong and misses the point, in Python 2 `range()` creates a list and in Python 3, `range()` creates a range object, which is not exhausted like a generator

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you may create yourself your own generator in order to be able to modify its behavior, as follows for example:

```
class myRange:

    def restartFrom(self, start):
        self.start = start

    def get(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        while self.start != end:
            yield self.start
            self.start += 1


myRange = myRange()

for i in myRange.get(1,10):
    print(i)
    # Restart from the beginning when 6 is reached
    if i == 6:
        myRange.restartFrom(0)

# It prints: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
```