# For loop not executing two times

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop

i'm new in python, i'm learning about lambda and map, but when i was trying some things, i found that one loop was not executing, and i want to know why.

I know it's kind useless to do that, but when i iterate the same list two times, the second time is not executed.

```
salarios = map(lambda emp: emp.salario, empleados)
print("------SALARIO-------")
for salario in salarios:
    print(salario)
print("-----SALARIO2--------")
for salario in salarios:
    print(salario)
```

I get

```
------SALARIO-------
6700
7500
2100
2150
1800
-----SALARIO2--------
```

i expect get

```
------SALARIO-------
6700
7500
2100
2150
1800
-----SALARIO2--------
6700
7500
2100
2150
1800
```

why is it happend? it's some lenguaje optimization?

Comment: yup `map` runs only once... duplicate

Comment: Read about generators

Comment: you can save the map() results for multiple iterations in a list, which might help show what's happening here: `salarios = list(map(lambda emp: emp.salario, empleados))` . In python 2 maps returned lists automatically.

Comment: @DanFarrell I was going to say that! Yes, do `list(map(...))` and it works.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/resetting-generator-object-in-python

Comment: could not find a suitable duplicate BTW.

Comment: @EthanK a little far-fetched. I searched and thought I would find a dupe in seconds, but nooo. (that doesn't mean it isn' t a duplicate)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I guess... The problem is around not understanding generaters, though.

Comment: the problem may have come from a bad habit of using `map` in python 2 to do everything, from looping to dishwashing. I used to do that for a small period of time too, just to showoff with `map` and `lambda` (and if I could use `reduce` in the same expression, all the better)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, `map` is a generator (since Python 3). Once consumed in the first loop, it's "empty" the second time.

You'd be better off without `map` + `lambda` combination (that's a general rule). In your case, change:

```
salarios = map(lambda emp: emp.salario, empleados)
```

by

```
salarios = [emp.salario for emp in empleados]
```

now you have a list comprehension, which you can iterate as many times as you want.

(your current expression is equivalent to generator comprehension `salarios = (emp.salario for emp in empleados)` which is easier to read when you only want to iterate *only once* on it)

*Note*: in Python 2 `map` returns a `list`, so people abused of `map` and `lambda` expressions, sometimes even without iterating, just to call a function on elements of a list.

With Python 2, your code would have worked, but would have had a vicious portability bug when switching to Python 3 (The `list(map(lambda emp: emp.salario, empleados))` expression that `2to3` tool proposes fixes that, but is slower & even harder to read than a comprehension)