# Python unexpected behaviour

Tags: python

The following code:

```
coords = zip([0], [0])
for a, b in list(coords):
    print("{}, {}".format(a, b))
```

outputs `0, 0` as expected. But the following code:

```
coords = zip([0], [0])
mylist = list(coords)
for a, b in list(coords):
    print("{}, {}".format(a, b))
```

outputs nothing. Why is that the case?

Python version:

```
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: You have exhausted the generator here `mylist = list(coords)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Just found out what I need to do in such a case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/resetting-generator-object-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `zip` returns an iterator, which means that once you iterate over it, it's exhausted and you cannot iterate over it again.

Your first iteration is being done when you make it a `list`:

```
mylist = list(coords)
# At this point coords has been exhausted, so any further `__next__` calls will just raise a `StopIteration`
```

When you try to iterate over it again using the `for` loop, it doesn't yield any more items, because there's nothing else to return. Everything has been iterated using `list`.

In order for your `for` loop to work, you need to either:

- Loop over `mylist`, which is a `list` and hence it keeps indices of the items (it can be randomly accessed), which means that you can go over all the elements as many times as you want.
- Get a fresh iterator by calling `zip([0], [0])` again.