# How can I know if a filter() returned anything in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, generator

In Python3 `filter()` (and `map()` etc.) returns a filter object, which you can iterate over.

What if I need to know if that will generate anything? Since [generators cannot be reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1271353/204658) I'm not sure how to do that. You could turn the filter object into a list using `list()` which in many cases is possible, but I've always felt that the Python3 version of lazy evaluation (generators) is impossible to use as I'm "used to" from many functional languages, i.e. it just works. Not so in Python3.

Specifically, I need to check if any of two filter functions returned something. Something like this

```
l1 = filter(f1, data)
l2 = filter(f2, data)
if len(l1) > 0 or len(l2) > 0:
    ...
```

To make this work I have to evaluate `l1` and `l2` using `list()` before checking the length.

One other way would be to use `itertools.tee()` to duplicate the filter objects and then get the first element from the duplicates. However this seems a very roundabout way leading to a lot of extra code.

Is there a cleaner pythonic way to do the same?

Comment: There is no way to determine whether a generator returns something or not before evaluating it. At least you have to call `next()`.

Comment: Think about how you'd write the filter in Python. `for item in input: if predicate(item): yield item`. Until you've consumed the first item you don't know if there'll be any. Until you've materialised the list of the result there's no information about how long it will be.

Comment: [This module](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576410-lazy-lists/) (unfortunately, a gist, I haven't found a `pip` module) lets you build a lazy list over an iterator, which behaves like what I assume you expect. This comes with the same limitations as lazy lists in other languages: unlike Python generators, the lazy list takes up space for any elements you have evaluated. If you just want to see if a generator is empty or not, the chain workaround from the linked page is superior. If you want familiar lazy lists in Python, this does it.

Comment: Duplicate, fair enough. What frustrates me is the search functionality in StackOverflow, I tried to find the answer using about a dozen different searches...