# Why do we reset test generator in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have seen many places that people reset the test generator in Keras while predicting the output, but I am unable to find why.
Can you make it clear?

I have a custom generator like this

```
def dual_datagen(df,clinical_features,batch_size=20):
    eff_generator=data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(df,directory='/content/data',
                                               target_size=(img_shape,img_shape),
                                               x_col='img_id',
                                               y_col=col,
                                               class_mode='raw',
                                               shuffle=False,
                                               batch_size=batch_size)
    number_of_batches = len(clinical_features)/batch_size
    counter =0
    while True:
        x_1 = eff_generator.next()
        x_2 = np.array(clinical_features[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]).astype('float32')
        counter += 1

        yield [x_1[0], x_2], x_1[1]
        if counter >= number_of_batches:
          counter = 0
```

How can I reset it?

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1271320/14142345)

In the case of data science though, it is even more obvious.
Making a dataset generator usually involves data cleaning, piping and prepocessing. This makes generators usually very slow to initialize.

So, instead of creating a brand new generator, you just use the `itertools.tee` to multiply the generator. The only downside to is that you now have two versions of the generator in memory. In most cases, that is not a problem. Data storage usually is of less concern then time use.

You can use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to re-use the generator.

Does this answer your question?