# Difference between job generators for multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, iterator, generator, python-multiprocessing, yield

I need to run a same function with different input parameters, it will cost a very long time but luckily I know it only need 1 CPU core, so I decide to run them parallelly with multiprocessor package in python. Assuming I have 4 cores in my CPU and I have 8 different parameters to try, and therefore I think the time cost of the following code will be about 2 times as the time cost to run a single job:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def a_hard_work(parameter):
    #do some time-cost work with parameter as input

class IterableAdapter:
    """https://stackoverflow.com/a/39564774"""
    def __init__(self, iterable_factory, length=None):
        self.iterable_factory = iterable_factory
        self.length = length

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.iterable_factory())
        
def loader(param_set):

    def loader():
        for param in param_set:
            yield param

    return IterableAdapter( lambda: loader() ) 

def worker(parameter):
    a_hard_work(parameter)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    param_set = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

    tasks = loader(param_set)

    with Pool() as p:
        for i in p.imap_unordered(worker, tasks):
            try:
                pass
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

However it cost much longer time than I excepted, so I checked the usage of my CPU and I found only 1 CPU core was being used during this script was running, all other 3 cores had no load.

Then I changed my code to the following:(which I thought should be same):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def a_hard_work(parameter):
    #do some time-cost work with parameter as input

def loader(param_set):
    for param in param_set:
        yield param

def worker(parameter):
    a_hard_work(parameter)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    param_set = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

    tasks = loader(param_set)

    with Pool() as p:
        for i in p.imap_unordered(worker, tasks):
            try:
                pass
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

This time the script worked as I excepted, but what is the difference between two ways I generate jobs?

Comment: both versions use 4 CPU on my Linux.

Comment: BTW: shorter `def loader(param_set): yield from param_set` and maybe even shorter `tasks = iter(param_set)`