# python best way to check if generator is empty

Tags: python

Can anybody help me. my question is in the code comments.
I want to check if the generator items is empty.

```
name = 'john'
while True:
   n = (x for x in names if x['name'] == name) #generator
   if len(n) != 0: #this is wrong obviously. But this is what I want to do with the generator items.
      break
   name = input('Enter name > ')
```

Comment: Is the purpose of the iterator only to check if the name is found?

Comment: yes. But if not found, it should ask again to enter another name from available names

Comment: If that's your usecase (and not just example), then on `next` or whatever check you use, python will evaluate it anyway. So just use loop to check the containing (to exit early with first) or make this n a list instead of generator.

Comment: Yeah I have no choice but to use list again. since I want to get the last and first and count the items. I thought it will be easily possible with generator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`next(<generator>, None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on it and check for the result not being `None`, or use your custom value if you expect `None` as a part of the generator output.

Alternatively, don't, but catch the [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration):

```py
try:
    next(<generator>)
except StopIteration:
    print("I'm empty")
```

Comment: Or as Python does: "better ask for forgiveness" - just do `next(gen)` and catch

Comment: @h4z3 exactly :) Though multiple of try/except are ugly, but that's a matter of preference/readability.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, But it will skip the first item right? that's what I'm still confused about using next. Since my result should be only 1 item

Comment: but i will try this :)

Comment: @mark12345 `next(x for x in ["first"])` outputs `"first"`, so it won't "skip" it, but if you intend to use the generator later on you'll need to [do something else too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1271481/5994041).

Comment: Oh I'm gonna check it out. I actually like to use generator specially this is huge data.

Comment: Thank you. I found this usefull. I used next(gen, None) instead. So I can still use While loop and ask the user to input if gen is None

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the purpose of the iterator is to find that whether the name is known. If it's the case, you can use `any`:

```
if any(x['name'] == name for x in names):
    break
```

Or even shorter without `break`:

```
while all(x['name'] != name for x in names):
    name = input('Enter name > ')
```

Comment: I wanted to suggest this but with `x for x in...`, OP gets empty or x. `any` would only say *if* they got it there, not fetch the element

Comment: @h4z3 the OP is not using the found element anyway.

Comment: In this code snippet, yes. But as `x` is some bigger struct and OP's looking for a matching one, then I think it's safe to assume they want to use it afterwards

Comment: That's better idea. but how I can fetch the element if it is found?

Comment: @TomKarzes `names` is not a list of `str`, it's a list of `dict`, so `name in names` won't work.

Comment: @mark12345 if you want to fetch the element, then Peter's answer is better.

Comment: @TomKarzes it's a list of dicts, not a dict. We're finding a dict with a given key-value.

Comment: @bereal yes that's what actually what I want. My question is incomplete (because I don't know yet earlier what exactly the right question)
if the name is found in the list, I will fetch the items or index not only the name.

Comment: @mark12345 depending on context, it may get simpler if you create another lookup dict `by_name = {x['name']: x for x in names}`

Comment: @bereal I must be tired - sorry for all the confusion.  Nice King Crimson avatar ;)