# Python3 list comprehension from two generators processes only the 1st inner loop

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, generator

I'm trying to make a list comprehension from two generators

```
g1 = (a for a in range(3))
g2 = (b for b in range(5))
l = [(i, j) for i in g1 for j in g2]
print(l)
```

but instead of a list of 15 tuples it only returns results of the first inner loop.

`[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)]`

However, if to put the generators into the comprehension itself, the result is as expected.

```
l = [(i, j) 
    for i in (a for a in range(3))
    for j in (b for b in range(5))]
print(l)
```

Do I miss something, or is it just a kind of a "feature"?

Here are cProfile outputs for both versions.

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 t.py:1(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 t.py:1(<module>)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 t.py:2(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 t.py:3(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 t.py:1(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 t.py:1(<module>)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 t.py:2(<genexpr>)
       18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 t.py:3(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator can only be consumed ones. After that it is empty.

In your first example `g1` is used for the first item of `g2`. For each further item of `g2` it is already "used up" and returns nothing.

In your second example for each iteration of the outer loop a new fresh generator is created.

Further reading: [Resetting generator object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1271320/18667225)

Comment: I see, it's clear now. I paid my attention to the first generator since it looked like the outer loop happened only once, while the reason was the depleted second generator. Thanks =)